# Crystal - How to have shared attributes and/or type among subclasses of parent

Tags: oop, crystal-lang

I believe this is a general OOP question, but I'm using Crystal insofar as that matters.

What is the right way to handle a situation where I have child classes that need to share a type but that type isn't the parent. For example, let's say I have animals: cats and dogs, and I also have baby animals: kittens and puppies. I want the kittens and puppies to be their own type with their own set of "parent" methods.

```rb
class Animal
end
class Dog < Animal
end
class Cat < Animal
end
class Puppy < Dog
  property? needs_milk = true
end
class Kitten < Cat
  property? needs_milk = true
end
```

I know that if all I needed was some properties or methods I could do this via a mixin:

```rb
module BabyAnimal
  property? needs_milk = true
end
```

but for my actual use case, I want to guarantee that all members of an array "are" BabyAnimals (and thus have baby animal methods and properties) i.e.

```rb
[] of Kitten | Puppy
```

So it feels like inheritance is the only / right way to do this.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: All members of the array? What array? There's no array in the code you provided.

Comment: Good point, edited to include a generic array example to show my previous understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modules are part of the type hierarchy. If you use the type restriction `BabyAnimal`, you can be assured that it only matches types that include that module.

```
Kitten.new.is_a?(BabyAnimal) # => true

array = [] of BabyAnimal
array << Kitten.new
array << Puppy.new
```

Comment: Wow, Crystal is great! That's just what I would expect and it seems obvious now that I see it, I just didn't expect something so simple and logical to work so seamlessly.